# Get subpath in Raphael.js between two points, not positions

Tags: svg, raphael, bezier

I have a path in Raphael.js which is a bezier curve.  Two lines intersect this path.  I can get the points of the intersections with `Raphael.pathIntersection()`.  I want to get the path string for the subpath between these two points, though.  Raphael.getSubPath() needs to know the positions along the path, but I don't know these positions, just the absolute points.  How can I go about getting the positions of these intersections so I can find the subpath?

Thanks

Edit: below is the intersection object that is returned for the first of the two intersections that make up the start and finish of the subpath I want to find.  I can see from this which segment the intersection occurs in, but how to get the actual position along the path from its start from this information?

```
0: Object
  bez1: Array[8]
    0: 746.6695658365885
    1: 444.9913024902344
    2: 746.6695658365885
    3: 444.9913024902344
    4: 767.3333333333334
    5: 383
    6: 767.3333333333334
    7: 383
  bez2: Array[8]
    0: 743
    1: 427
    2: 750
    3: 428.5
    4: 752.5
    5: 428.8333333333333
    6: 761
    7: 432
  segment1: 1
  segment2: 9
  t1: 0.330626006717131
  t2: 0.5304347826090153
  x: 751.9768115942079
  y: 429.0695652173915
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually pathIntersection also returns the positions on the intersecting paths as t1 & t2 in the return object, not only the absolute position.

Comment: Thanks - can you explain what the t1 and t2 values actually correspond to?  They are decimals between 0 and 1 but they don't appear to be the percentage distance across the whole path.

Comment: They are the percentages on the intersecting segments, not the whole path. The intersection object includes both the segment numbers and the percentages along that segment. Hope it's clear..

Comment: Thanks - that is clear, but I'm still not sure how I can find the position along the whole path - I don't know how to get the length of each segment, for example?

Comment: That's another question, but for your needs you don't need it, just use getSubPath on the intersecting segments. Other segments are either fully part of the subpath, or not included at all.

Comment: My intersecting segment looks like this: C,644.66,392.6,650,390.5,667,391.  Raphael doesn't recognise this as a path (presumably because it doesn't start with an "M"), so I am unable to find it's length or use it to find a subpath?

Comment: So the previous segment should end with the starting point of the intersecting segment, you can add it as the M part to the intersecting segment.

Comment: Yep, using the last point of the previous segment did indeed make this work for me.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I know this is a bit late to join the conversation, but could any one of you describe the final solution, perhaps with some example code? I have the exact same problem but couldn't make it work so far.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that I guess I can't understand english, so in the following case:

```
       _|_________
       \|
        |\
        | \
        |  \
 _______|___\
        |
```

(can't post figure here, hope you understand)
with Raphael.pathIntersection(), it would return something similar to this:

```
0: Object
    bez1: Array[8]
    bez2: Array[8]
    segment1: 1
    segment2: 1
    t1: 0.49131376884437716
    t2: 4.686749827219845e-13
    x: 221.6492901831065
    y: 425.40404348103067
    __proto__: Object
1: Object
    bez1: Array[8]
    bez2: Array[8]
    segment1: 2
    segment2: 1
    t1: 0.9999999999901484
    t2: 1
    x: 281.50000000000495
    y: 325.3666666666513
    __proto__: Object
2: Object
    bez1: Array[8]
    bez2: Array[8]
    segment1: 3
    segment2: 1
    t1: 5.420619967753905e-13
    t2: 0.9999999999989502
    x: 281.49999999999204
    y: 325.3666666666728
    __proto__: Object
    length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
```

subpath of every intersecting segment can be obtained by 
subpath on these segment one by one, with Raphael.getTotalLength and Raphael.getSubpath

```
        |
        |
        |
        | 
        |  
        |___
        |

        |
       \|
        |\
        | \
        |  \
        |   \
        |

       _|
        |
        |
        | 
        |  
        |   
        |
```

and them join these subpath into one to get the final path?

```
       _|
       \|
        |\
        | \
        |  \
        |___\
        |
```